# Can anyone explain what do they mean by, 'The past is just a story we tell ourselves'?

Tags: time, reality

Even if we keep repeating our past to ourselves, still it is not just a story, I think so. It is something that happened to us, the experience is not a story.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Who is 'they'? Could you share some more background?

Comment: It's is a dialogue from the movie, 'HER'.  I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @AnilPadule, instead of replying in the comment thread, edit your question with the appropriate information.

Comment: This might be better suited for [movies](http://movies.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote appears to be from the movie *Her*. While citing random things on the Internet usually doesn't go very far, there is an interesting comparison to this idea with similar thoughts of [Marcus Aurelius](http://thoughtcatalog.com/jeremy-sheeler/2014/02/the-past-is-just-a-story-we-tell-ourselves/).

To summarize the comparison, the following of Marcus Aurelius was quoted (without citation):

> Our life is what our thoughts make it.
>
> You have power over your mind – not outside events. Realize this, and you will find strength.
>
> Very little is needed to make a happy life; it is all within yourself in your way of thinking. ([Meditations 7](http://classics.mit.edu/Antoninus/meditations.7.seven.html)?)

It seems to fit with the ideas of stoicism, being detached from pain.

As the OP alludes to, there are other philosophic traditions that have a different approach. As just one example, certain branches of Christianity understand sin as not just a story we tell ourselves but rather as something that has real temporal effects that must be addressed (i.e., through confession and performance of penance), and simply telling oneself a different story does not change one's actual state.